# Spring-security cannot match "?parameter" format?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-roo

I use spring-security to secure my web, when I'm learning it by spring-roo generated config file in applicationContext-security.xml, in `<http>` node:

```
 <intercept-url pattern="/userses?form" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
```

It means when you want to create a Users object, firstly you need to login to get ADMIN permission. But actually it didn't work. Check the log:

```
2012-05-06 11:39:11,250 [http-8088-7] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/userses'; against '/userses?form'
```

The framework use the /userses instead of /userses?form to compare with, authentication process skipped as string didn't match. To verify this I also try another url:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/userses/abc" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
```

I requested the /userses/abc, it detected user is not authorized, and moved to /login page, checked the log:

```
2012-05-06 11:46:44,343 [http-8088-7] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/uesrses/abc'; against '/userses/abc'
```

So my question is: Doesn't spring-secure 3 support "?parameter" pattern or I missed something to config to support this?
PS: All the code is generated by roo without modification, also wonder why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default [spring security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/ns-config.html) uses ant style matching, which can't match on parameters. Regex matching, however, *can* match on parameters

Try defining it like so:

```
<http request-matcher="regex">
  <security:intercept-url pattern="\A/userses\?form.*\Z" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
</http>
```

Don't know why Roo doesn't do this automatically.  Seems like it should.

Comment: @JerryCai Perhaps you should open up a new question.  It's difficult to read code in the comments, and it will help others with the same problem if they can find it as a distinct question on SO.

Answer (score 6):

That behavior is defined by the ["request-matcher"](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/appendix-namespace.html#nsa-http-request-matcher) in use. As indicated by the documentation, the default is "ant", which indicates to use an [AntPathRequestMatcher](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/util/AntPathRequestMatcher.html), and an alternative is "regex", the [RegexRequestMatcher](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/util/RegexRequestMatcher.html). The javadocs (linked) give specifics about the matchers, including the fact that the former matches against a request's "servletPath + pathInfo", and the latter against its "servletPath + pathInfo + queryString".