# how to use params in spring security antmatchers

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

How should I use parameters like  this in antmatchers in spring ?
I have many URLs that start with /sUrl and have  different params.
This Code doesn't work!

```
//don't works
    .antMatchers("/sUrl?params={url:\"reports/Manager\",subSystem:\"ABS\"}/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ABS')")
```

sUrl?params={url:%22reports/Manager%22,subSystem:%22ABS%22}

Comment: Sorry...I am using spring security 4

Comment: No, I think it can't help.I want a guide to how to use parameters in matching... like this part:?params={url...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring-security cannot match "?parameter" format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10467930/spring-security-cannot-match-parameter-format)

Comment: @dur, Granted, but the versions have changed so much since that an update is most welcome!

Comment: @faraa AFAIK there is no change in `RegexRequestMatcher` since version 3.1. IMHO an update is not neccessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably solve your problem using `regExMatcher`

See [HttpSecurity regExMatcher method](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#regexMatcher(java.lang.String)) for more details.

Comment: I used regExMatcher but seems it doesn't work for something like this: @RequestMapping(value = "sUrl", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public RedirectView renderUrl(@RequestParam(name = "params") String params) beacuse params recieved with @RequestParam not a part of URL...Thanks

Comment: I think it work with PathVariable  but not with RequestParam

Comment: @faraa That's wrong, query parameters (`GET`) are part of the URL. If you use `POST` then the parameter is not part of the URL.

Comment: @faraa: you can test your regex online, for example: https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html